# How to get Java Version with eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am doing eclipse plugin development and I am trying to get the java version from the project. I have an instance of the project as an IProject. The API can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProject.html). Is there a way to tell which version of java (i.e. JRE System Library) the project has running?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the version of Java the project has running'? Do you mean the required execution environment? Or the Java compliance level if it is a Java project? Or what?

Comment: Well you can use cmd and type (java -version) or Eclipse>Windows>Preference>Compiler or Installed JREs

Comment: I want to check in java.. I believe @greg-449 knows what I am talking about.

Comment: This might help: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html#create(org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject)

Comment: Well it is in the `.classpath` file as the `kind="con"` entry for the path starting `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER`. The `JavaCore` class has methods for dealing with this but I don't know what they are in detail.